# NSUserDefaults for loop for switchCollection

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I've make a mySwitchCollection and I need to retrieve the boolForKey value from it to set on or off the switch on my view.
This is the code but I've problem for the [defs boolForKey:arrayCostanti[i]];

arrayCostanti is a static NSString *arrayCostanti[] = {k3D,kAnimazione};

How I can push my arrayCostanti[i] value to boolForKey?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    //Leggo dal defs gli stati di ogni switch e gli setto lo stato
    //NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //mySwitch1.on = [defs boolForKey: k3D];

    //ciclo for per settare tutti gli stati degli switch che ho raccolto nel mySwitchCollection
    for (int i = 0; i <= 45; i++){
     mySwitchCollection[i].on = [defs boolForKey:arrayCostanti[i]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you are storing it correctly as well.

I'm going to assume 'k3D' is a defined NSString for your key.

```
// saving
mySwitch1.on = YES;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:mySwitch1.on] forKey:k3D];

// retrieving

BOOL switchOn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:k3D];
```

The big thing to remember is that NSUserDefaults can only store the main object types, and BOOL is not one of them. So make sure you set your BOOL to an NSNumber first, and you should be good to go.